# How to remove trim caulk orange peeled wall

Tags: walls, trim

We're replacing the trim in our room, but the trim that is there is taller than the trim that we want to replace it with. So after removing the old trim, there's a caulk line for the original.

The wall is orange peel textured, and I would love if we didn't have to repaint.

The texture of the caulk is kind of dry, I don't think it was a silicone caulk, but I don't really know.

So, I'm looking for advice on how to remove this old caulk.

Answer (score 1):

How do you plan on not painting if the new trim is lower than the old trim?  Personally, I'd go with the same if not larger trim to hide any imperfections left by the old trim, but maybe that's just me.

To remove old caulk, just use the flat edge of the painters multi-tool to scrape it away.  Be careful not to dig into the wall or pull up the paper from the drywall.  For anything left, sand it down.  You'll probably want to have some extra drywall mud or spackle available to fix any spots and to cover any screw/nails that were previously covered by the old trim.

And then, yes, you'll need to paint.  It's easier to do a first coat on the trim and the walls before installing the trim.  Then all you have to do is touch-up any nail holes or scrapes.

Comment: Well the hope was that since the wall was already painted when the trim was installed, it would have been ok when the trim was removed.

Comment: From my experience, any time you've had part of a wall covered up for a long while, the paint will look different once exposed (fading, dirt, etc).  I don't think you'll avoid repainting.  Just practice feathering in the paint so you don't have to repaint the entire wall.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, trim is caulked with an acrylic painter's caulk. Scrape off as much as you can without damaging the drywall, then try washing the rest off with a water dampened soft cloth. You may be lucky and find the caulk is water based and will come off with a little effort.  Mitch is right, the color may be different behind the old trim. It will be very likely some painting will be in your future. If the old caulk was painted, then it is not 100% silicone, as paint won't stick to silicone.